# Checking one of the conditions for whether $p(x,y)$ is a metric or not

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to check if $p$ is a metric on $\Bbb R^2$ where $p(x,y)=2|x_1 - y_1|+3|x_2 -y_2|\ge 0$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R^2$.

I have checked all the conditions.I wanted to know if my approach to MS4 (the triangle inequality) is right?

let $z=(z_1,z_2) \in \Bbb R^2$

$$\begin{align} p(x,y)= & 2|x_1 - y_1|+3|x_2 -y_2|\\
\le & \,2\left(|x_1 - z_1|+|z_1 - y_1|\right)+ 3\left(|x_2-z_2|+|z_2-y_2|\right)\\
= & \left(2|x_1 - z_1|+3|x_2-z_2|\right) + \left(2|z_1 - y_1|+3|z_2-y_2|\right)\\
=& p(x,z)+p(z,y)
\end{align}$$

Then $p(x,y)\le p(x,z)+p(z,y)$.
Therefore, $p$ is a metric

Comment: Please take the time to write your mathematical formulas in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As currently depicted your formulas are hard to read, which will deter people from taking the effort to understand and answer your question.

Comment: Yes it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your triangle inequality proof is fine, just applying the usual one for $\Bbb R$ and rearranging. This works for any weighted sum of "coordinate metrics".